# Using Stacks in Python

Tags: python, module, stack

Hi I am new to using python and was learning how to use stacks in python. I found some web examples that use this command:

```
from pythonds.basic.stack import Stack
```

But when I tried using this command, I get this error message back:

```
ImportError: No module named pythonds.basic.stack
```

I tried google searching where to get this module installed from but can't seem to find it. Any help in identifying where I can get this from or any other way to use stack will be appreciated!

Comment: well, the [module](https://github.com/bnmnetp/pythonds/blob/master/basic/stack.py) appears to be quite trivial, just copy it and study how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to install it with `pip`, like so

```
pip install pythonds
```

or you can download the tarball and install it yourself, which you can find on [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pythonds)

Comment: examples can be seen here.
http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/BasicDS/ImplementingaStackinPython.html

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to fix that error:

```
sudo pip3 install pythonds
```